# QueryBuilder expression in FormBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I would like to know how to use queryBuilder expression within a **formBuilder**.

The general use of query builder in formBuilder is :

```
$builder->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'=>Entity::class,
    'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder("e")
                  ->where("e.active=1");
    },
));
```

Now, I would like to use `->expr()->in()` within `where` statement.
The problem is, unlike entity repository, `$er->expr` doesn't works.

What should I do to access `expr` within the `where` statement?

Comment: Another way is to create the query inside the repository and call the method in the form, don’t forget that you should return an instance of QueryBuilder not the result itself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function (EntityRepository $repo) {
    $qb = $repo->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $qb
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in(...))
    ;

    return $qb;
}
```

Comment: It does. I have hundreds of these in my projects.

Comment: Its not `$er->expr`, but `$qb->expr()`

Comment: Ah~ I see... The trick was to make an instance of `EntityRepository`... Thanks

Comment: @Preciel An instance of `QueryBuilder`, not `EntityRepository`.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the expression builder accessing the EntityManager and then get the expression builder, as example:

```
$builder->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'=>Entity::class,
    'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
        $expr = $er->getEntityManager()->getExpressionBuilder();
        // .. 
    },
));
```

Hope this help

Comment: You answer is also valid, but Padam's answer is more easy to remember... ;)

Comment: Yes @Preciel the other answer is more easy